# Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '19853'

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have gone through all the questions with this title, but I am still stuck here.

Here is my **php.ini** conf settings

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.idekey="xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

**here is `phpinfo()`**

[image: phpinfo]

**here is PhpStorm server config**

[image: phpstorm server config]

**PhpStorm xdebug config**

[image: phpstorm xdebug config]
[image: DBgp proxy]

Now if I submit the request in debug mode in PhpStorm REST client, I get this error.

> Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '19853'

I don't know how else to fix this.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm -- official manuals.

Comment: Its working fine with web applications. I am facing this problem while debugging REST API